# SAP B1 DI API - Differences between SBObob GetItemPrice and CompanyService GetItemPrice?

Tags: sdk, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

What's the main differences between the DI API methods for GetItemPrice?

The SBObob accepts less parameters (and returns a Recordset), but as far as I can tell it provides the accurate price for the item taking into accounts any Business Partner discounts and the quantity of the item, etc...

The CompanyService GetItemPrice call seems to take a lot more parameters AND returns a ItemPriceReturnParams object - but information is scarce in the SDK help file for this method. And there's no information on this return type as well... I've already searched the SAP archive forums... Also I'm using version 9.2.

Answer (score 1):

ItemPriceReturnParams have three properties as you may know:

- Currency
- Discount
- Price

Comment: So the main reason to use CompanyService GetItemPrice instead of SBObob Getitemprice is that the CompanyService one returns more information (currency, discount) where as the other one only returns price? I'm guessing the Price will always be the same, whichever method you use then, and the only reason to use CompanyService would be if you a) wanted to avoid ado objects and b) didn't need the currency or discount, is that correct?